# Case use and translation of ‘Welche Liebe ist dir wichtiger?’

Tags: translation, german-to-english, pronoun, dative

> Welche Liebe ist dir wichtiger?

About the above question; why is *dir* in the dative case and what would be the translation of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question translates as "Which love is more important *to you*"?

The indirect object "to you" (dir) requires the dative case.